# Manipulating element's position from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make an **alert** that when I call it, it's position over certain elements, so here is my code:

```
function special_alert(msg, target_element_id){

  var element = $(target_element_id).position();
  console.log(element)
  var html = '<div class="special-alert warning" style="position: absolute;top: '+element.top +';left:'+ element.left+ '">'
            + '<span class="special-alert-closebtn">&times;</span>'
            + '<strong>Warning!</strong>'+ msg
            +'</div>';

  $('body').append(html)

}
$(()=>{
  special_alert('hello', '#author')
})
```

The top and left properties aren't accepted by the browser:
[The Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLA50.png)

Nothing seems to be wrong, even the position property is working.

Please help.

Comment: just need to add `'px'` to the values

Comment: thanks, I can't vote you up because i have low reputation. Excuse my dumb moments!!!

Comment: All good man! :)

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev you should also post your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 var html = '<div class="special-alert warning" style="position: absolute;top: '+element.top +'px;left:'+ element.left+ 'px;">'
            + '<span class="special-alert-closebtn">&times;</span>'
            + '<strong>Warning!</strong>'+ msg
            +'</div>';
```